# Add a Submit Form Inside an AMP Story

Tags: amp-html, amp-list, amp-bind, amp-form

I want to add a favorite button with counter inside an AMP Story page like the AMP Documentation example.

https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/favorite_button/

However, even though the JSON info are loaded correctly, when i click the favorite heart a

[Action] "FORM.submit" is not whitelisted []

error is prompted in the console.

I determined that if the amp hmtl has a  tag inside, the form submission is not whitelisted.

I am just pasting the code from the AMP Documentation website inside a
 
tag and more or less everywhere i may put the form, the whitelisted error appears.

How can i implement a favorite counter like button in we are not allowed to put forms inside an AMP story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i implement a favorite counter like button in we are not
>   allowed to put forms inside an AMP story?

You can't.